# Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0 - Visual Basic.NET with Microsoft Access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2012, vba

I encountered this problem when trying to run my program. The codes goes this way

```
    Private Sub mainmenu_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    conString = "C:\Users\Nur Amira\Documents\SEM 5\SDP\sdddd\sdddd\Database1.mdb"
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection(conString)
    con.Open()
    Sql = "select * From Login"


    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(Sql, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "Role")
    totrec = ds.Tables("Role").Rows.Count - 1

    For i = 0 To totrec
        cmboxpos.Items.Add(((ds.Tables("Role").Rows(i).Item(2).ToString)))
    Next
End Sub
```

It will popup a window box notify the error as title with the

```
 Dim con As New OleDbConnection(conString)
```

highlighted. Anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

A connection string is much more than just the file path/name. Examples here:

[Connection Strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/)